# Images not scaled correctly in Internet Explorer/Firefox, works in Chrome

Tags: html, css, wordpress

**The Problem**

I am working on a WordPress website where I have problems with Internet Explorer/Firefox rendering the page differently than Chrome. I am trying to get Internet Explorer/Firefox to render the page like Chrome does it.

Chrome render:
[image]

Internet Explorer (and similar Firefox render):
[image]

**What I have tried so far**

1. If I remove the frame around the images, then the rendering is correct. So I suspect the problem to lie in frame css classes.

**The Questions**

- Are there any known problems with IE/Firefox which could cause this?
- Any hints on which part of the css to look at?

**Source**

The part of the HTML which adds the pictures:

```
<div class="main-holder">
<div id="content" class="content_full_width">
<div class="one_half"><p>Content goes here&#8230;<br />
<span class="su-frame su-frame-align-left su-frame-style-default"><span class="su-frame-inner"><img alt="" src="112-12521-551x220.jpg" /></span></span></p>
</div><div class="one_half_last"><p>Content goes here&#8230;<br />
<span class="su-frame su-frame-align-left su-frame-style-default"><span class="su-frame-inner"><img alt="" src="112-12521-551x220.jpg" /></span></span></p>
</div><br class="clear" />
```

Relevant frame css classes:

```
/*      Frame
---------------------------------------------------------------*/

.su-frame,
.su-frame-inner { display: block; }
.su-frame-align-left {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
}
.su-frame-align-center {
    float: none;
    margin: 1em auto;
}
.su-frame-align-right {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 1em 1em;
}
.su-frame img {
    display: block !important;
    float: none !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    border: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
.su-frame-style-default {
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #ccc;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #ccc;
}
.su-frame-style-default .su-frame-inner {
    padding: 2px;
    border: 4px solid #eee;
}
```

Relevant column css classes:

```
/*----------------------------*/
/* 5. Multi Columns
/*----------------------------*/
.clear {clear: both;}
.one_half, .one_half_last, .one_third, .one_third_last, .one_fourth, .one_fourth_last, .one_fifth, .one_fifth_last, .one_sixth, .one_sixth_last, .two_thirds, .two_thirds_last {padding-bottom: 20px;}


#content .one_half {float:left;width:342px;margin-right:30px;}
#content .one_half_last {float:right;width:342px;margin:0;}
#content .one_third {float:left;width:220px;margin-right:30px;}
#content .one_third_last {float:right;width:220px;margin:0;}
#content .one_fourth {float:left;width:152px;margin-right:36px;}
#content .one_fourth_last {float:right;width:152px;margin:0;}
#content .one_fifth {float:left;width:124px;margin-right:23px;}
#content .one_fifth_last {float:right;width:124px;margin:0;}
#content .one_sixth {float:left;width:100px;margin-right:20px;}
#content .one_sixth_last {float:right;width:100px;margin:0;}
#content .two_thirds {float:left;width:470px;margin:0;}
#content .two_thirds_last {float:right;width:470px;margin:0;}
#content .three_fourth {float:left;width:550px;margin:0;}
#content .three_fourth_last {float:right;width:530px;margin:0;}


.content_full_width .one_half {float:left;width:455px !important;margin-right:30px !important;}
.content_full_width .one_half_last {float:right;width:455px !important;margin:0 !important;}
.content_full_width .one_third {float:left;width:293px !important;margin-right:30px !important;}
.content_full_width .one_third_last {float:right;width:293px !important;margin:0 !important;}
.content_full_width .one_fourth {float:left;width:208px !important;margin-right:36px !important;}
.content_full_width .one_fourth_last {float:right;width:208px !important;margin:0 !important;}
.content_full_width .one_fifth {float:left;width:168px !important;margin-right:23px !important;}
.content_full_width .one_fifth_last {float:right;width:168px !important;margin:0 !important;}
.content_full_width .one_sixth {float:left;width:140px !important;margin-right:20px !important;}
.content_full_width .one_sixth_last {float:right;width:140px !important;margin:0 !important;}
.content_full_width .two_thirds {float:left;width:595px !important;margin:0 !important;}
.content_full_width .two_thirds_last {float:right;width:595px !important;margin:0 !important;}
.content_full_width .three_fourth {float:left;width:690px !important;margin:0 !important;}
.content_full_width .three_fourth_last {float:right;width:685px !important;margin:0 !important;}

.content_full_width .two_thirds_last .one_third, .content_full_width .two_thirds_last .one_third_last, .content_full_width .two_thirds .one_third, .content_full_width .two_thirds .one_third_last {width:280px !important;}


.content_sidebar .one_fourth, .content_sidebar .one_fourth_last {width:105px !important;}
.content_sidebar .one_third, .content_sidebar .one_third_last {width:145px !important;}
.content_sidebar .one_half, .content_sidebar .one_half_last {width:235px !important;}
.content_sidebar .two_thirds, .content_sidebar .two_thirds_last {width:325px !important;}

#footer .one_half {float:left;width:455px !important;margin-right:30px !important;}
#footer .one_half_last {float:right;width:455px !important;margin:0 !important;}
#footer .one_third {float:left;width:305px !important;margin-right:30px !important;}
#footer .one_third_last {float:right;width:305px !important;margin:0 !important;}
#footer .one_fourth, #footer .one_fourth_last {float:left !important;width:227px !important;margin-right:23px !important;}
#footer .one_fourth_last {margin-right:0px !important;float:right !important;}
#footer .one_fifth {float:left;width:177px !important;margin-right:23px !important;}
#footer .one_fifth_last {float:right;width:177px !important;margin:0 !important;}
#footer .one_sixth {float:left;width:146px !important;margin-right:20px !important;}
#footer .one_sixth_last {float:right;width:146px !important;margin:0 !important;}


#content .tabs-area .one_half,
#content .slide .one_half {float:left;width:310px;margin-right:30px;}
#content .tabs-area .one_half_last,
#content .slide .one_half_last {float:right;width:310px;margin:0;}
#content .tabs-area .one_third,
#content .slide .one_third {float:left;width:194px;margin-right:35px;}
#content .tabs-area .one_third_last,
#content .slide .one_third_last {float:right;width:194px;margin:0;}
#content .tabs-area .one_fourth,
#content .slide .one_fourth {float:left;width:141px;margin-right:30px;}
#content .tabs-area .one_fourth_last,
#content .slide .one_fourth_last {float:right;width:141px;margin:0;}
#content .tabs-area .one_fifth,
#content .slide .one_fifth {float:left;width:108px;margin-right:28px;}
#content .tabs-area .one_fifth_last,
#content .slide .one_fifth_last {float:right;width:108px;margin:0;}
#content .tabs-area .one_sixth,
#content .slide .one_sixth {float:left;width:92px;margin-right:20px;}
#content .tabs-area .one_sixth_last,
#content .slide .one_sixth_last {float:right;width:92px;margin:0;}
#content .tabs-area .two_thirds,
#content .slide .two_thirds {float:left;width:425px;margin:0;}
#content .tabs-area .two_thirds_last,
#content .slide .two_thirds_last {float:right;width:425px;margin:0;}
#content .tabs-area .three_fourth,
#content .slide .three_fourth {float:left;width:485px;margin:0;}
#content .tabs-area .three_fourth_last,
#content .slide .three_fourth_last {float:right;width:485px;margin:0;}


.content_full_width .tabs-area .one_half,
.content_full_width .slide .one_half {float:left;width:420px !important;margin-right:30px !important;}
.content_full_width .tabs-area .one_half_last,
.content_full_width .slide .one_half_last {float:right;width:420px !important;margin:0 !important;}
.content_full_width .tabs-area .one_third,
.content_full_width .slide .one_third {float:left;width:267px !important;margin-right:30px !important;}
.content_full_width .tabs-area .one_third_last,
.content_full_width .slide .one_third_last {float:right;width:267px !important;margin:0 !important;}
.content_full_width .tabs-area .one_fourth,
.content_full_width .slide .one_fourth {float:left;width:190px !important;margin-right:36px !important;}
.content_full_width .tabs-area .one_fourth_last,
.content_full_width .slide .one_fourth_last {float:right;width:190px !important;margin:0 !important;}
.content_full_width .tabs-area .one_fifth,
.content_full_width .slide .one_fifth {float:left;width:155px !important;margin-right:23px !important;}
.content_full_width .tabs-area .one_fifth_last,
.content_full_width .slide .one_fifth_last {float:right;width:155px !important;margin:0 !important;}
.content_full_width .tabs-area .one_sixth,
.content_full_width .slide .one_sixth {float:left;width:127px !important;margin-right:20px !important;}
.content_full_width .tabs-area .one_sixth_last,
.content_full_width .slide .one_sixth_last {float:right;width:127px !important;margin:0 !important;}
.content_full_width .tabs-area .two_thirds,
.content_full_width .slide .two_thirds {float:left;width:575px !important;margin:0 !important;}
.content_full_width .tabs-area .two_thirds_last,
.content_full_width .slide .two_thirds_last {float:right;width:575px !important;margin:0 !important;}
.content_full_width .tabs-area .three_fourth,
.content_full_width .slide .three_fourth {float:left;width:650px !important;margin:0 !important;}
.content_full_width .tabs-area .three_fourth_last,
.content_full_width .slide .three_fourth_last {float:right;width:650px !important;margin:0 !important;}


.content_sidebar .tabs-area .one_half,
.content_sidebar .slide .one_half {float:left;width:205px !important;}
.content_sidebar .tabs-area .one_half_last,
.content_sidebar .slide .one_half_last {float:right;width:205px !important;}
.content_sidebar .tabs-area .one_third,
.content_sidebar .slide .one_third {float:left;width:125px !important;}
.content_sidebar .tabs-area .one_third_last,
.content_sidebar .slide .one_third_last {float:right;width:125px !important;}
.content_sidebar .tabs-area .one_fourth,
.content_sidebar .slide .one_fourth {float:left;width:88px !important;margin-right:28px !important;}
.content_sidebar .tabs-area .one_fourth_last,
.content_sidebar .slide .one_fourth_last {float:right;width:88px !important;}
.content_sidebar .tabs-area .one_fifth,
.content_sidebar .slide .one_fifth {float:left;width:66px !important;}
.content_sidebar .tabs-area .one_fifth_last,
.content_sidebar .slide .one_fifth_last {float:right;width:66px !important;}
.content_sidebar .tabs-area .one_sixth,
.content_sidebar .slide .one_sixth {float:left;width:56px !important;}
.content_sidebar .tabs-area .one_sixth_last,
.content_sidebar .slide .one_sixth_last {float:right;width:56px !important;}
.content_sidebar .tabs-area .two_thirds,
.content_sidebar .slide .two_thirds {float:left;width:280px !important;}
.content_sidebar .tabs-area .two_thirds_last,
.content_sidebar .slide .two_thirds_last {float:right;width:280px !important;}
.content_sidebar .tabs-area .three_fourth,
.content_sidebar .slide .three_fourth {float:left;width:320px !important;}
.content_sidebar .tabs-area .three_fourth_last,
.content_sidebar .slide .three_fourth_last {float:right;width:320px !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

add to ".su-frame img" the following rules:

`max-width:100%;

height:auto;`

Comment: This did unfortunately not fix the problem. Same results as the screenshots above.

Comment: as i can see from the screenshot, i think you can try: .content_full_width .one_half .su-frame img{ max-width:100% !important; height:auto !important; }.   So the images will scale to maximum 455px - (borders+paddings)